# directory shared via nfs is unavailable -restart required?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have two VMs.
First one shares a directory:

```
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox1:~$ cat /etc/exports 
/home/pawel/somedir 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox:~$
```

And second one uses auto.nfs to get access to shared dir:

```
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox2:~$ cat /etc/auto.nfs
/mnt/somedir_10 -fstype=nfs,soft,timeo=5,retry=5 192.168.1.10:/home/pawel/somedir
```

And it works:

```
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox2:~$ ls /mnt/somedir_10/
file_in_somedir
```

When directory from VM1 is inaccessible I get an error:

```
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox2:~$ ls /mnt/somedir_10/
ls: cannot access '/mnt/somedir_10/': No such file or directory
```

But when it is available again, i still cannot access the folder.
To get access i have to restart autofs service:

```
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox2:~$ sudo systemctl restart autofs
pawel@pawel-VirtualBox2:~$ ls /mnt/somedir_10/
file_in_somedir
```

Two questions:

1. Is there any other way (apart from restart autofs) to retrieve connection to shared dir?
2. Is there automatic way (like when you plug in USB stick) to find out something is available under nfs-share ?

Comment: why do people give downvote without any comment? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: Question doesn't seem suitable for stackoverflow to me. Should probably be on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Every works fine. The problem was I was checking it too quick.
timeo parameter in auto.nfs is in tens of seconds so timeo = 5 means next check will be in 50 seconds.